# Adding onChange Event to Kendo DatePicker Dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, kendo-ui, datepicker, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add an onChange event to the Kendo DatePicker and noticed that there is not an easy way to go about doing this, unfortunately.

I was able to add an override by using jQuery but I can only get this to work if I know the name of the DatePicker. I'm providing an example of this below for reference.

```
<!-- [ begin ] invoke onChange event -->


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function onChanger() {
            alert("Change :: " + kendo.toString(this.value(), 'd')); // show the value

            document.forms['submitForm'].submit(); // submit the form
        }

        $("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
            change: onChanger
        });
    }); 
</script>

<input id="datepicker" name="datepickers" />

<!-- [ end ] invoke onChange event -->
```

The problem is I'm looping through items which dynamically are building these DatePickers.

So my code looks like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
    .Name("AllTeachersObjectives_" + rec.CalendarGroupID)
    .Value(rec.AllTeachersObjectives)
    .Max(DateTime.Now.AddYears(10))
    .Events(e => e.Change("startChange"))
)
```

How can I dynamically invoke the `onChange` event from using a name of a DatePicker that is dynamic?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

TIA

Comment: It's not clear what you wanna do. Do you want to dynamically invoke the change event or add it? The title of question says something, but the question itself says something else.

Comment: Also, how come you don't know the name of the date-picker? Isn't `"AllTeachersObjectives_" + rec.CalendarGroupID` the name of the date-picker? You should be able to reconstruct this name with the `CalendarGroupID`.

Comment: Same event handler for all DataPickers or each one unique or just one handler for just one particular DatePicker?

Comment: Can you not add the change event listener to a class, instead of an id?

Comment: @ataravati I want to dynamically invoke the change event and add it. Ideally, I want to be able to pass the name of the element and value into the onchange event. I know do not how to do this in the Kendo UI datePicker dynamically.

Comment: @ataravati I know the name of it yes, but I am unsure how to pass this into the onchange event that fires off. Typically, in a input form I would simply do "onChanger(AllTeachersObjectives_" + rec.CalendarGroupID, this.value)" but I am not sure how to do this in the Kendo UI datepicker.

Comment: @Fruitbat - I want the same event handler for all datepickers.

Comment: @Mark - What I want to do is as soon as they leave the datepicker feild, and there has been a change, for it to fire off an event that submits and updates the value in the database. Can this be accomplished using a class? If so, could you please explain how I would go about doing that? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what an event is? The change event is a function that's executed when the value of the date-picker changes. Why on earth do you want to dynamically add the event to the date-picker? That doesn't make sense. Also, in your date-picker the change event function is called `startChange`. And, you never use it.